# Flash communication options for 2-player-games

Tags: ruby, flash, actionscript, eventmachine

I am currently working on a project that embeds a flash game, that uses Smartfoxserver for the flash communication. That communication is mostly just synchronizing the cursor and object movements between the two players.

Since I am not a flash guy, but a ruby programmer, I got curious: What kind of communication options does flash offer for this kind of time sensitive data exchange? I was thinking of writing a ruby-eventmachine based communication server to minimize the dependencies on external programs. Would that even be feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't have a complete answer for you, because I'm not done myself, I have found myself in almost the exact same position as you.

My current approach is for my ruby server to essentially just be a socket server that handles all of the communication between clients, however I personally intend on keeping any of the logic outside of the server ( unless I run across a reason to change that idea).

If you haven't done any socket programming in ruby, I recommend the following as a jumping point.  This is an IBM document on Ruby Socket programming and discusses an approach for asynchronous data:
[Ruby Sockets - IBM](https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/l-rubysocks/l-rubysocks-a4.pdf)

I think what it ultimately comes down to as well will be performance.  I currently use a version of my ruby server in my daily work, but the data doesn't have to be updated in a time sensitive manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a server in (almost?) any language that supports sockets and manage your clients with that.

From a flash perspective you could use ruby, but I don't know how fitted ruby would be for the task...I mean, you can make a [PHP socket server](http://www.enobrev.com/chat_tutorial.php) but it would not handle much stress.

An alternative to SmartFoxServer could be open sourced [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5), written in Java.

If you want to know about flash built in capabilities in handling p2p:
[Flash p2p: Everett Church](http://justin.everett-church.com/index.php/2008/05/23/astrop2p/)
In Flash Player 10 adobe added Live media (RTMFP) support- Media was always sourced from the publishing peer. In Flash Player 10.1 beta they introduced groups and application-level multicast.

However, you would still need a server ([Stratus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/)) to handle introductions and manage active connections. ( Also, I regard it as geared towards flash video, Stratus does not support shared objects or scripting. So with Stratus, your applications will be clients communicating directly with each other.)

Edit:
After re-reading your question and the answer provided by Beanish, I think the first time I got your question wrong. So I just re-wrote my answer...